# qt слот для замены кнопки на изображение

Tags: c++, qt

Для одной кнопки я могу сделать такое:

```
p1->setIcon(QIcon(":resource/1.png"));
p1->setIconSize(QSize(48,48));
```

А как сделать слот который делал бы тоже самое?

Comment: если ты о том как слоты создавать то вот https://youtu.be/IUrLxMv-HGA?t=971 например, в файле cpp в внутри слота пишешь свой код по замене кнопки. чтобы открыть меню создания слота жми правой кнопкой мыши по нужной тебе кнопке в режиме дизайна интерфейса

Comment: Мне нужен слот который делает тоже самое что и я указал в вопросе.

Comment: Нужен когда по замене кнопки внутри слота,код для замены определенной кнопки я уже указал в вопросе

Comment: создаешь слот, потом  берешь свой код и переносишь в слот

Comment: Ну я тоже так думал,переношу просто код указанный в вопросе в слот и все,но у меня в этом коде указана кнопка p1,при запуске ругается что эта кнопка не объявлена

Comment: добавь код целиком в тему

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь и за отклик,но уже разобрался,кому интересно сделал так:void myClass::mySlot()
{
    QPushButton* btn = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    if ( btn == p1)
    {
            p1->setIcon(QIcon(":resource/1.png"));
            p1->setIconSize(QSize(48,48));
    }
    .....
}

Comment: ох фак,что я наделал,извините.

Answer (score 3):

Помогли на другом форуме,сделал так:

```
 void myClass::mySlot()
{
    QPushButton* btn = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    if ( btn == p1)
    {
            p1->setIcon(QIcon(":resource/1.png"));
            p1->setIconSize(QSize(48,48));
    }
    .....
}
```